# Application Deployment in close infrastructure

Tags: deployment, devops

our team adopted agile development style. We have desktop application which is installed on more than 5 thousands computers. These computers are in customer network. In network there are distribution points but one point is main. It means we copy binary files into main point and then there are distributed into all distribution points to install client computers. 
For us it means a lot of manual work. We have own Azure DevOps server (TFS) which is not connected with customer newtork because of source code security. We can copy binary files by some shared folder but nothing else. 
How we do application deployment? There are steps:
1) Copy binary files to main distribution point.
2) Create deltas by xdelta tool.
3) Copy all new files to all distribution points by robocopy.
4) When copy is done we change version in manifest file and copy again. 
5) We have manually created database alter file so we upgrade database by this file.

I wanted to use Jenkins to automate these steps. Problem is that customer said he don't want to install any other software to his servers. All steps need to be done in customer network. 
What devops tool should I use to automate these steps by pipeline? When we copy to distribution points it is parallel as same as database deployment because there are more than 70 database instances.

It is not about one application. We have more application which we would like to deploy more effective.

Thank you.

SOLUTION: I solved this problem by using MSDeploy tool. I wrote own small application which can read simple XML configuration tool and launches MSDeploy through MSDeploy API. DacPac deployment is solved by SqlPackage.exe. So I can deploy whole application with all references and dependent parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a configuration managment tool to roll out desktop software Windows clients.
Microsoft inhouse solution is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/